# SQL запрос получить запись, численное поле которой равно другому численному полю этой же записи

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Нужен SQL запрос, позволяющий получить запись, у которой одно числовое поле равно другому числовому полю этой же записи

Answer (score 1):

Выводит записи из таблицы myTable, где значение поля field_1 равно значению поля field_2

```
select * from myTable t
where t.field_1 = t.field_2;
```